# Probability of drawing candies in a certain order using permutations

Tags: probability

I am solving this question for a pre-calc class:

> "Pat reaches into a bowl containing twenty distinguishable pieces of candy and grabs a
> handful of four. Suppose that ten of the pieces are red and ten are brown.  What is the probability that the first two pieces selected are red and the last two pieces are brown?"

The correct answer is 6.96%

I found that one way to arrive at that answer is to multiply (10/20)(9/19)(10/18)(9/17); however, we have been working a lot with combinations, permutations, and Pascal's triangle, so this solution seems a bit too simple.

I do recognize that the denominator of my solution is the same as nPr (20,4), and that the numerator of my solution is the same as 2*nPr(10,2)... I just do not understand why we use permutations instead of combinations in this instance. I would assume that the denominator should be nCr(20,4) which is the total number of different handfuls.

Would someone be willing to explain or propose another solution? Thank you so much?

Comment: Not really sure about this, but I believe we've ... I mean ... you ... have diabetes.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is exactly right. You've shown a way to answer the question that amounts to using probabilities (each of your bracketed fractions can be thought of as a probability). An alternative, maybe more combinatorial way, is to think of how many ways we could pick four sweets (which is $\binom{20}{4}$)

Two must be red and two brown; there are $\binom{10}{2}^2$ ways to pick the right selection.

*But* the order matters; there are $\frac{4!}{2!^2}=6$ distinct orderings ($BBRR$, $BRBR$, $BRRB$ etc); combining all this gives the result
$$\frac{\binom{10}{2}}{6\binom{20}{4}}=\frac{45}{646}$$

Answer (score 0):

The wording of the question is inappropriate. If you grab a "handful" of candies, how do you know which is first, which is second... ? It should have specified selecting one by one at random.

"... one way to arrive at that answer..." is actually the simplest here because an *ordered* (in a specified order) selection is needed.

You *can* use combinations to first get the probability that you have got $2$ each of red and brown in all possible orders as $\Large\frac{\binom{10}2\binom{10}2}{\binom{20}4}$ and then correct to get the desired order by *dividing* by $\Large\frac{4!}{2!2!}$ to get the particular order you want the colors to be,

but as you can see, this makes the solution unnecessarily complicated.

---

### PS:

Maybe the intention of the question was to first grab a handful, and then draw out one by one, which could then be solved using  a mixed formulation using both concepts, viz

$\Large\frac{\binom{10}2\binom{10}2}{\binom{20}4} \times \frac24\frac13\frac22\frac11$